# "Watchdog has expired" when I debug app with iPhone in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, jailbreak, watchdog

From yesterday, My iphone couldnot debug any apps.
In xcode, when I choose my iPhone as the debug target, and xcode build the app, link, and run into my phone,  several sencond later, the xcode finish running in my iPhone. And the console below show "Watchdog has expired.  Remote device was disconnected?  Debugging session terminated."

It is iPhone4s, iOS version is 5.0.1, and had jailbreaked, and update Cydia a few days ago.

It could not work on my other MBP yet.
How can I recover it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the bug in Cydia update and Jailbreaking.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to fixed? I think so at first, but not sure

Comment: I have install a app to set iPhone to SAFE MODE , it would disable all jailbreak app ,and the debug works.

Comment: how you do that is it possible with ipad too?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this post:

[App crashes with "Watchdog has expired." message. No stack trace or crash dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927310/app-crashes-with-watchdog-has-expired-message-no-stack-trace-or-crash-dump)

Here is **tc.**'s answer from that post

> "Watchdog has expired." could mean anything. The way the message is
>   worded suggests that the "local" GDB (running on your Mac) GDB timed
>   out waiting for data from the "remote" GDB (running on the phone).
>   Alternatively, "Watchdog has expired" might be from the phone's
>   console output shortly before it reboots.
>
> What does it display if you disconnect the device while your app is
>   running? What if you power it off? What if you issue a hard reset
>   (Sleep+Home for 10 seconds)?
>
> If it's causing the device to reboot, there's something seriously
>   wrong happening. Your app shouldn't be able to take the phone down,
>   but sometimes something slips through (IIRC, UIImagePickerController
>   on some version of 2.x had a problem where either your app would get
>   killed or the phone would reboot, depending on which kicked in first).
>   "Large set of bitmaps" sounds like it might be causing CoreAnimation
>   (or IOSurface or whatever) to run out of video memory.
>
> I would hesitate to do drawing in a background thread unless you're
>   very careful about thread-safety (to a first approximation,
>   CoreAnimation is and UIKit isn't except a few functions that were made
>   "thread-safe" in 4.0).

Hope this helps you.